# Error mount samba share

Tags: networking, samba, cifs

I'm trying to mount a samba folder, run the command:

```
mount -t cifs 192.168.1.10/srv/smb/Publico /home/douglas/samba
```

But it is returning the error:

```
mount.cifs: bad UNC (192.168.1.10:/srv/smb/Publico)
```

Does anyone know how to solve?

Comment: `mount -t cifs //192.168.1.10/srv/smb/Publico /home/douglas/samba`

Comment: @A.B. Thanks for helping me, being prompted for a password for root, but there is no password for this folder.

Comment: Comments are for clarification and not for new questions

Comment: Fixed comment :)

Comment: It will ask root password of the computer whose folder you are mounting